# Jenkins installation error: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Getting error on Jenkins installation.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Openjdk version 1.8.0_312
Entered command: (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/)

Does anyone have a solution for this??

```
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jenkins
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/91.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 95.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
(Reading database ... 314328 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking jenkins (2.332.3) ...
Setting up jenkins (2.332.3) ...
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-05-22 18:50:57 IST; 3ms ago
    Process: 31287 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 31287 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 installed jenkins package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.17) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

After doing `sudo service jenkins start` every thing will work properly
you can check if **jenkins** started successfully by `sudo service jenkins status`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Ubuntu 22.04. It turns out that Jenkins works well with only OpenJDK (11, 8) distribution of Java and not with other distributions like BellSoft JDK 19 which I had installed.

Install OpenJDK 11 (or 8) using the command `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre` or set the default Java version to JDK 11 (or 8) using the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` if you have other distributions of Java installed already.